# Process communication

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an output file to be used as input for other process. I got an example but getting error when trying to write. See if you can help correcting this or suggest a way to pass information to an external process:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExternalProcessComm
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\test_out.txt";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //start the exe
        p.Start();

        //write something 
        p.StandardInput.Write("Test Text"); // Getting error here

        //read the output 
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Redirection only works on console mode apps.  Notepad is a Windows GUI app.  Your code cannot work.

Comment: Are you trying to allow the user to type something into "Notepad" and then capture the file they create?

Comment: @user2026794 **[XY-problem:](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)** *You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.* (Y is your notepad solution in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;` - you've already done so for StandardOutput, but you need to do both.

As for the actual program you're launching, you're going to want to test with a program that uses the standard input and output - notepad does not.

Comment: You forgot to read the second line of my response - notepad does use standard input or standard output.

Comment: What exactly are you really after?

Comment: Then as a test, invoke the `sort` program. It takes input, provides output and that will be enough to test this half of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting the standard input (this is the error message you might be getting right?

Add

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Just fyi regarding the interaction with notepad: This will not be working as you might expect.